# empty inherited entity Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have for exemple this schema

```
abstract class Class1

    attr1
    attr2

class Class2 extends Class1

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany("Class3")
    */
    attr3Array

class Class3

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Class2")
    */
    attr3
```

This is just a pseudo code to present my problem. 
When I try to generate my database I have this error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Entity 'Class2' has to be part of the discriminator map of 'Class1' to be properly mapped   
  in the inheritance hierarchy. Alternatively you can make 'Class2' an abstract class to avoid this exception from occurring.
```

But I want to create instances of Class2, I don't want an abstract Class2
Is there an other way to model my entities ?

Comment: Did you check the `namespace` of each class to be same? Did you `use` the parent class in child classes?

Comment: This is not a code problem but an model problem, if I set the Class2 abstract or if I add an argument to the class 2 this works, but I need to generate Class2 objects so I can't have an abstract class. And I don't need extra arguments in my class2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining the parent class as a mapped superclass. If there is an `@ORM\Entity` annotation, you'll need to remove that.

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Class1
{
}
```

You may also have to make this class non-abstract if Doctrine doesn't like MappedSuperclasses to be abstract.

More information on inheritance mapping can be [found in the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). Also you may find a more suitable solution in there for what you need.